# JQueryMobile: Making an Ajax call after transitioning to result page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying out JQM to build the following sequence:

1. User presses Go on Page1. 
   `<a href="userListPage.jsp" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Go</a>`
2. Transition to userListPage
3. Show "Loading" animation and make an Ajax call fetch results and populate list on userListPage.

The normal JQM way is to show a loading animation after step 1 and transition to userListPage showing the result list.

But I want to show the Result page first and then load the actual data (via Ajax).

I tried following but this does not even make the Ajax call.

```
<script>
var mainloaded = false;
$('.userListPage').live('pageshow', function(event) {   //Workaround to show page loading on initial page load
    if(!mainloaded) {
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    }
});

$('.userListPage').live('pagecreate', function(event) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "getUserList",  
        type: "GET",
        data: dataVar,
        success: function(result) 
        {   
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            mainloaded = true;
            userListContent.innerHTML = result;
        },
        error: function(e){  
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }   
    });
});
```

Any suggestion as to how to do this?

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/methods.html maybe $.mobile.loadPage and then refresh the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the pageshow event get triggered? Also, you may want to bind to the pageshow event for you ajax call. Something like this:

```
$('.userListPage').live('pageshow', function(event) {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "getUserList",  
        type: "GET",
        data: dataVar,
        success: function(result) 
        {   
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            userListContent.innerHTML = result;
        },
        error: function(e){  
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }   
    });
});
```